# Initiating background process for running php file as background from another php page

Tags: php

I want initiate one php page as background process from another php page.

Answer (score 3):

Use [popen()](http://php.net/popen):

```
$command = 'php somefile.php';
pclose(popen($command,'r'));
```

This launches `somefile.php` as a background process.

Answer (score 2):

This is a technique I used to get around restrictions applied by my webhost (who limited cronjobs to 15 minutes of execution time, so my backup scripts would always timeout).

```
exec( 'php somefile.php | /dev/null &' );
```

The breakdown of this line is:

- `exec()` - [PHP reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) Runs the specified command, as if from the Linux Command Line.
- `php somefile.php`: Invokes PHP to open, and run, *somefile.php*. This is the same behaviour as what would happen if that file was accessed through a web browser.
- `|` ("pipe") - Sends the output of the proceeding command to a specified target. In this instance, it would "pipe" the content which would normally be read by the web browser accessing the file.
- `/dev/null` - A blackhole. No, not kidding. It is a place where you send output if you just want it to disappear.
- `&` - Appending this character to the end of a Linux command means "Do not wait - Send this to the background and continue."

So, in summary, the provided code will execute a PHP script, return no output, and not wait for it to finish before continuing onto the next line.

(*And, as always, if any of these assumptions on my part are in error, I would love to be corrected by more knowledgeable members of the community.*)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure, that the background process is not terminated when the processing of the page finished. If you are on a Linux system, you could try to use the nohup command:

```
$command = 'nohup php somefile.php';
pclose(popen($command,'r'));
```

If it still gets terminated, you could try the "daemon" command.